# Что значит пересечение с активным фильтров в Google таблице?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

хочу объединить ячейки, выдает ошибку: Невозможно объединить по вертикали ячейки, которые пересекаются с активным фильтром. Почему так?

Comment: Пойди туда, не знаю, куда :) Наверное, установлен фильтр и объединение будет мешать фильтрации... Пример покажете?

Comment: Не стесняйтесь задать вопрос подробнее, приложите скриншот, чтобы всем было ясно, применяете ли Вы фильтр и какие именно ячейки пытаетесь объединить. Или все это уже не актуально?